# PHP mkdir and apache ownership

Tags: php, apache, mkdir, owner, chown

Is there a way to set php running under apache to create folders with the folder owned by the owner of the program that creates it instead of being owned by apache?

Using word press it creates new folders to upload into but these are owned by apache.apache and not by the site that they are running in. This also happens using ostickets. For now we have to SSH into the server and chmod the folder, but it would seem there would be a setting somewhere to override the ownership outside of any program that does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Safe_mode` is turn on on your server. The function `mkdir()` creates folder with owner ("apache", "none", ..) that different of the current script owner. And scripts couldn't upload (move, copy) files into that folder with another owner (that is not like current script owner).

Disable `safe_mode` and that would be work.

See http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php for details.

P.S. With enable `safe_mode` you can't use `chmod()` function in php.

Comment: **Warning This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.**

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to put the apache user and the "customer users" in a new group. Additional the directory should use the sticky bit `SGID` so each new file got the group assignment to this new group. This way the webserver and the "customer users" can work with the files without any problems

```
[17:57] progman@proglap /tmp/test $ ls -al /tmp/test
total 9
drwxrwsr-x  2 root users   48 Apr  1 17:55 .
drwxrwxrwt 36 root root  9264 Apr  1 17:53 ..
```

As you see the directory got the stick bit `SGID` and the owner is the "users" group in which I (`progman`) am. No if another user adds a file the group automatically get set to this group

```
[17:55] proglap ~ # touch /tmp/test/x
```

This is executed from root. Now we get:

```
[17:57] progman@proglap /tmp/test $ ls -la /tmp/test
total 9
drwxrwsr-x  2 root users   72 Apr  1 17:59 .
drwxrwxrwt 36 root root  9264 Apr  1 17:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root users    0 Apr  1 17:59 x
```

As you see the added file is from root, but the group is set to `users` and this way **I** can remove it

```
[18:00] progman@proglap /tmp/test $ rm x
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `x'? y
[18:01] progman@proglap /tmp/test $ ls -la /tmp/test
total 9
drwxrwsr-x  2 root users   48 Apr  1 18:01 .
drwxrwxrwt 36 root root  9264 Apr  1 17:53 ..
```

Keep in mind that you still need to change the `chmod` if you want to *edit* the file as `rw-r--r--` is just *group read access*. But changing the `chmod`, maybe even working with `umask`, is better than dealing with root-access and using `chown`.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no. You can't "give away" ownership of a file to another user, unless you're root. You could investigate using the "[AssignUserID](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/perchild.html#assignuserid)" apache directive to force that particular vhost to run as a particular user/group. With that Apache/PHP would create any files with the appropriate ownership

Comment: Just in case somebody else thinks this could be the way to go (using the mpm_perchild_module) - which I did think: from the link: **This module is not functional. Development of this module is not complete and is not currently active. Do not use perchild unless you are a programmer willing to help fix it.**

Answer (score 0):

Check out PHP [chown()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) function

Comment: This function will fail if not run by superuser.