# Why can't I create a directory within a recently created directory?

Tags: php, directory, mkdir, safe-mode, umask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP mkdir and apache ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560762/php-mkdir-and-apache-ownership)

EDITED TO REFLECT NEW PROBLEM:

Thanks to your help I can create a directory within a directory recursively, but I am unable to create multiple folders within those created folders.

Code:

```
$timelineID = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['timelineID']));
mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/audio", 0777, true);
mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/image", 0777, true);
mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/product", 0777, true);
```

Again, the first mkdir() executes successfully, the second one does NOT.

Error: Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid/gid is 206601/206601 is not allowed to access (the directory I just made) owned by uid/gid 25000/25000 in (file.php) on line 13

Comment: Have your tried: `mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/audio", 0777, true);`? Without the umask? With true the dirs are created recursively.

Comment: Also check you have "just made that directory" and didn't create it in FTP/SSH first.

Comment: That works for one directory, thanks! but it doesn't work for multiple... here is my code for multiple... the first one works the others fail

Comment: mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/audio", 0777, true);  
mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/image", 0777, true);  
mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/product", 0777, true);

Comment: What OS and version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: What @Robbie is saying is this: is it possible that `timelines/${timelineID}` already exists? If so, that first `mkdir()` call won't change the owner or permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir(path,mode,recursive,context)
```

with recursive and context being optional params

e.g.

```
mkdir("timelines/{$timelineID}/audio", 0777, true);
```

works on PHP 5+

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: we got that to work, but it doesn't work for multiple folder creations.

Comment: Perhaps you have a umask issue?  Did you check the permissions on the automatically-created intermediate directory?  You could try clearing the umask with `$old = umask(0);` before the `mkdir` call to see if that's the problem (and `umask($old)` afterward to restore it).